# filter remove an element from an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which I have declared in the state .

```
this.state = {
  typeAdded: [] 
}
```

Now, I have two tables both are having the check-boxes. Now, what I do is that if user clicks the checkbox then I am adding that value in this array, if it is un-checkd  then I am removing that value from that array . Now Here ,

```
if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
      this.setState({
        typeAdded: this.state.typeAdded.concat([type])
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          areResumesSameType: this.state.typeAdded.every((val, i, arr) => val === arr[0])
        })
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        typeAdded: this.state.typeAdded.filter(function (a) {
          return a !== type 
        })
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          areResumesSameType: this.state.typeAdded.every((val, i, arr) => val === arr[0])
        })
      });
    }
```

Now, Here there are only two types of values are there `tracked or untrakced`.

So the array will have ,

```
["tracked", "tracked", "untracked", "tracked", "untracked"] kind of values . It represents which type of table value is checked.
```

Now, when I try to remove one of the value from this table on unchecking then while removing it is removing all the values that matches as I am using `filter` . So, what I am trying is to remove the only one value at that time, because others might have been checked but they are also getting removed .

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: why not changed the array  typeAdded to an object that map each checkbox to a value?

Answer (score 1):

`array.filter()` is not suitable for your setup. If you plan on having `typeAdded` be an array of strings, `[""]`. If you have multiple values that are the same, the method cannot effectively remove just a single item based on a value.

If you want to keep `typeAdded` as is, you can try toggling a value based on index instead.

See codesandbox here for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bardeen-7rxmh

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    typeAdded: []
  }

  handleOnChange = (event, index) => {
    const newState = [...this.state.typeAdded]
    if(event.currentTarget.checked){
      newState[index] = "tracked"
      this.setState({
        typeAdded: [...newState]
      })
    } else {
      newState[index] = "untracked"
      this.setState({
        typeAdded: [...newState]
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e, 0)}/>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e, 1)}/>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e, 2)}/>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e, 3)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Essentially, you just need to remove `.filter()` and toggle values by index instead.

Comment: Here the values tracked and untracked comes as  a type from that method itseldf. So, it gets added

Comment: @ganesh, not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean, if the checkbox gets unchecked, you just want that item to be removed?

Comment: Yes, I mean as I have added in the question that if we uncheck then it might be from the table tracked or untracked, from that list this should get removed